# Issue with html form and php using Xammp

Tags: php

I have installed XAMPP to simulate a php server environment on my pc.  Unfortunately my html form will do nothing when I hit submit.  Here is html:

```
    <html>
    <form>
    <form action="http://localhost/New/nn.php" method="post">

    Why don't they play poker in the jungle?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="jungle" value="treefrog"> Too many tree
    frogs.<br>                         
    <input type="radio" name="jungle" value="cheetah"> Too many cheetahs.   
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="jungle" value="river"> Too many rivers.<br> 
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br>

    </form>
    </html>
```

Here is php:

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

       if (!empty($_POST['jungle'])) {
         if ($_POST['jungle']=="cheetah") {echo "You got the right
         answer";}
         if($_POST['jungle']=="treefrog"){echo "You selected treefrog but
         answer is cheetah\n";}
         if($_POST['jungle']=="river"){echo "You selected river but
         answer is cheetah\n";}
       }
       else { echo "You did not choose an answer for jungle.\n"; }

     }
    else { echo "Please submit the form."; }

    ?>
```

Comment: "Unfortunately my html form will do nothing" you should describe what happens, what you expect to happen and how they differ. Take a look at [ask]

Comment: Are you running this page from your WAMPP server? In case so, is this HTML inside a `<?php ?>` tag and the file in which it is has the .php extension?

Comment: When I hit the submit button, the page stays on the same page while what it is supposed to do(and this worked once on a actual web server) is tell you if you chose the right answer or not on a separate web page.

Comment: Pedro, tried doing what you suggested, did not help at all, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided, you do have two form opening tags:

```
<form>
<form action="http://localhost/New/nn.php" method="post">
```

That might be a source of your problem.

---

On chome for mac (latest version).

- Right click on your page, `inspect`
- Go to the `Network` tab and reload
- Click on your file name (for me `test.html`) and go to the `preview` tab. See how you have both tags
- Now back on the `Elements` tab, see how you have only the first one, hence sending you back to the same page (that is the default action)

Comment: That is not the issue, the form with the submit button will still be submitted.

Comment: Submitted to the right page (`http://localhost/New/nn.php`)? Is the php code in `nn.php` and the html in another file?

Comment: @ Thomas Dutrion:  Yes they are two different files in same folder

Comment: Could you describe more precisely how it is not working, as asked in other comments? Also, you can just use a relative path (`action="nn.php"`).

Comment: I have tried using relative path, does not affect situation, thanks for tip though.  What this is is a simple multiple choice question with a submit button.  There are 3 radio buttons.  When you choose a answer and hit submit, it should take you a new webpage where you learn if you chose the right answer or not.  What happens when I hit submit is the page flashes, and then just stays on the same page.  I once got it to work correctly on a actual web server(the reason I don't use it is a whole other problem) but never in Xammp.

Comment: Have you tried removing the first `<form>`? I'll edit my first answer soon with proof on Chrome for MacOS.

Comment: It is often something simple isn't it, lol.  I feel kind of dumb, but now I can proceed.